# What/Who is Randall Flagg?

Tags: stephen-king, the-dark-tower

Randall Flagg appears in several Stephen King books (and implied in some others)

What is he? Satan? Some evil spirit? In the movie version of the Children of the The Corn" He Who walks behind the rows" is called "God of the Old testament." Could Randall be God?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From his entry in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randall_Flagg), it seems that he is not a supernatural character, just a recurring villain, in spite of him being described as

> "an accomplished sorcerer and a devoted servant of the Outer Dark", with supernatural abilities involving necromancy, prophecy, and influence over animal and human behavior. His goals typically center on bringing down civilizations through destruction and conflict

It seems that he [learned these magic abilities](http://stephenking.wikia.com/wiki/Randall_Flagg), not that he was born with them due to some sort of supernatural origin (like being Satan or some sort of evil spirit).

> Walter learned the ways of Dark magic and became a very powerful sorcerer and to some extent becoming a sort of Demon with a "quasi-immortality".

Remember that the Dark Tower series

> connects different worlds/universes/Stephen King's works.

(that explains him appearing in other of King's works such as *The Stand* or *The Eyes of the Dragon*)

In this series he

> tries to keep protagonist Roland Deschain from reaching the Tower (the linchpin of existence) so he can claim it for himself and become a god.

but he does not have a supernatural origin.

Comment: So he serves the Outer Dark...is all he does based on a command? Or does he do what he just feels is right?

Comment: @Eld-Aryan, I don't know, but that probably deserves to be it's own question (I encourage you to do it). Many other users could help with quality answers and the information would be easier to find than if it's just being answered in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

http://stephenking.wikia.com/wiki/Randall_Flagg

> Flagg is described as "an accomplished sorcerer and a devoted servant
>   of the Outer Dark" with general supernatural abilities involving
>   necromancy, prophecy, and unnatural influence over predatory animal
>   and human behavior. His goals typically center on bringing down
>   civilizations, usually through spreading destruction and sowing
>   conflict.

Answer (score 0):

In the books [Randall Flagg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randall_Flagg) is a sorcerer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just go by the Stand alone. Randall Flagg is defeated in Las Vegas by the hand of God. King wrote that. So in my opinion King does have God in his universe, Tom Cullen is God's Tom when hypnotized, Mother Abigail has visions from God and Flagg probably isn't Satan (My bet is the Crimson King is Satan) but more of a powerful Demon. King also wrote that Flagg aka Walter serves the Crimson King as do most of King's antagonists like Pennywise, Barlow etc etc.

Comment: Can you provided sources for where you got these sentiments?

Answer (score -1):

In the movie the stand..he is the Devil for sure. There are many references to his being Satan. He himself states to Lloyd when he meets him " Pleased to meet you, hope you guess my name"...an obvious reference to the Devil. Also, He is called an "Apostate of Hell" by Stud Redman..and finally, When Larry is about to die at the end and Flagg asks if he has any last words, he states to Flagg.."Why don't you tell him your real name". Again. an obvious reference to the evil one..or Satan.

Comment: Pure speculation

Answer (score -1):

Flagg is sort of the devil, but what peaple don't get is that there's no reall Satan or God in the Stephan king universe, there both in constant conflict with one another but the two are not God or satan just really powerfull interdenominational beings often confused as being satan or God. To put it bluntly there both riduclusly powerful. the two are likely extremely wizards who are constant battle with one another.
Also to the one useing the wiki bad choice, the wiki doesn't really get flag in the stand right.

Comment: Can you provide any sources to support your answer?